# 1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Even after putting `local-infile=1` in `[mysql]` and `[mysqld]` section in `my.cnf` file in ubuntu os, i am still getting

> 1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Comment: I don't know what command you're talking about, but the solution seems to be to upgrade MySQL.

Comment: why downvote this! i was to post exactly the same thing, its a legimit question, i have latest version and nothing, it works from mysql console but not from web